# Implementing BDD with webdriver API (JBehave+Webdriver) 

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, jbehave

I'm trying to enhance my Webdriver script by implementing a BDD framework. I came to know about JBehave (JBehave+Webdriver) but before going ahead with this I have my concern over how much java code implementation is needed because I'm mainly into automation testing. 
As per my perception JBehave works in three steps:

1. Adding Story files
2. Implementing the story files into Java (I'm having problem with this step)
3. Implementing Webdriver calls.

So with this approach If I have a user story for example Register into the application then:

- Implement User Story
- Implementation in java- Implement the complete authentication logic in Java
- Implementing webdriver- Automate the user actions

Another example: I have a user story that executes a particular workflow & requires to do a set of operations on 5-6 pages then I'll need to implement/simulate the java code for this.

Is this the way JBehave works? Also are there any alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The five-step overview of jbehave:

1. Write story (Plain text)
2. Map steps to Java method (POJO)
3. Configure stories (only once)
4. Run stories (with any of: Ant, Maven, JUnit, Eclipse, IntelliJ)
5. View Reports (HTML)

You can visit for details of jbehave:
http://jbehave.org/

You can visit the following for tutorial example:
https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

The way JBehave works is as follows;

1. Write a story that describes a certain desired behaviour of the system. This story must be written according to the [JBehave DSL](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/grammar.html). The story essentially describes a series of steps in a Given/When/Then flow.
2. Implement the Given/When/Then steps in java code. This involves writing code against the webdriver API to interact with the application under test.
3. Run the story and analyse the results. Its either going to pass or fail.

I'm writing a fairly detailed blog post about this at the moment and will update this answer with a link when it is completed.

Answer (score 0):

jbehave works in one way and does not rely on presence or absence of webdriver
if you want to get how-to "in one page" you can look [here](http://ivendelacroix.blogspot.com/2014/02/part-6-jbehave-future-belongs-to-bdd.html?view=sidebar)

Java BDD frameworks http://java.dzone.com/articles/brief-comparison-bdd - as for me JBehave and Cucumber are best choices since have big and active communities

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble implementing the story files in "pure" Java then you should give [Ginkgo4j](http://paulcwarren.github.io/ginkgo4j/) a try.  It a Java port of RSpec that allows you to test the same way as RSpec, just in Java.

Add this dependency to your POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>ginkgo4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Create a JUnit test case specifying the Ginkgo4jRunner runner:

```
@RunWith(Ginkgo4jRunner.class)
@Ginkgo4jConfiguration(threads = 1)
public class MyTest {
  {
    Describe("ClassUnderTest", () -> {
      Context("#Method", () -> {
        BeforeEach(() -> {
          // before test logic          
        }); 
        JustBeforeEach(() -> {
          ClassUnderTest.Method();          
        }); 
        Context("given a context", () -> {
          It("should do something", () -> {
            // assertions
          });
        });
        Context("given a different context", () -> {
          It("should do something else", () -> {
            // assertions
          });
        });
        AfterEach(() -> {
          // after test logic
        });
      });
    }); 
  }
}
```